# Как удалить из папки все файлы которые меньше 100 байт?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Хочу реализовать удаление из папки `C:\Users\userprofile\Downloads\ppp` всех файлов меньше 100 байт?

Вот такой код использую , но где то ошибка:

```html
const fs = require('fs');
const path = 'c:\\Users\\userprofile\\Downloads\\ppp';
const max = 100
 
fs.readdir(path, (err, items) => {
    for (let i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
        const file = path + '\\' + items[i];
        (file => fs.stat(file, (err, stats) => {
      if (!stats.isFile()) return
      if (stats.size < max) {
        console.log('Удаление файла', file);
        console.log(stats.size);
        fs.unlinkSync(file, err => console.log(err))
      }
        }))(file);
    }
});
```